# Email messages incorrectly marked as spam

Tags: gmail

Frequently, emails that are from a person on my whitelist, are sent to spam, so I have to check spam countless times a day, in case I miss them.

Does anyone know:

- How do I stop this?
- Why is it happening, so I can avoid it recurring?

Comment: Do you have any filters that could cause that email to be moved to spam?

Comment: Are you using the "Not Spam" button when removing them from spam? If you don't add that signal and simply move the messages out, Gmail can't learn what's spam and what isn't.

Comment: You can create a filter for that specific sender.

Comment: Do you have any filters that could cause that email to be moved to spam? 
Possibly, but it's strange that an estimated 90% of the emails from this email address reach my inbox. How do I check filters please?

Comment: Are you using the "Not Spam" button when removing them from spam? If you don't add that signal and simply move the messages out, Gmail can't learn what's spam and what isn't. – Al E. Sep 18 at 14:18
OK thanks for that, I'll do that a few times and hope it learns. I don't  understand why an estimated 90% of the emails from this email address reach my inbox.

Answer (score -1):

This answer may be relevant depending on what email service you are using? If you have your own domain your ISP will be using the likes of SpamAssassin to move messages to spam. In this case, you should contact the ISP support and send them the header information of the white list messages marked as spam, for issue investigation.

Comment: The Asker is the recipient, not the sender.

Comment: My answer is relevant as the OP is checking _his_ spam